# How do I set the time on my Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, operating-systems, time

I run my ubuntu on a virtual machine and the time does not update. How can I set up my machine so that everytime I turn it on the time will be correct?

Ubuntu 12.04

running on a VMware VM with a W7 as host.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-time-synchronization-on-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: thank you. I had already followed this tutorial to no avail, hence the post.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Ubuntu as a Guest under VirtualBox then you should be aware that the system time is automatically kept in sync by the *Guest Additions*

Your solution in that case is to disable the Guest Additions, which can be achieved by executing

```
sudo service vboxadd-service stop
```

or

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxadd-service stop
```

You can then set the time as desired

To change date to **25 Jun 2015 12:48**, the command would be,

```
sudo date --set "25 Jun 2015 12:48:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your guest OS gets its clock from the host at boot, and this, hopefully, should keep the two synchronized. However, this does **not** occur, because intervals between timer interrupts (on which the OS bases its time keeping) are stretched and compressed by VMWare (and Xen, and VirtualBox, and HyperV, and...).

You have two solutions. Either you use a daemon (in VMWare Tools) which keeps host and guest synchronized, or you use the usual Linux time-keeping ntp daemon. I strongly recommend this second option, actually for both host and guest (if the host is not a Linux, there are alternative solutions!).

```
     sudo apt-get install openntpd
```

will take care of (nearly) everything for you. I prefer *OpenNTPd* to the more usual *NTPd* because it is a lighter, simpler, safer, newer implementation of the very same protocol.

If you really want to be shocked, you can read [here](http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/Timekeeping-In-VirtualMachines.pdf) VMWare's manual about time-keeping in VMs, in order to get an appreciation of the complexity of the topic.